# Dirty Tracking of embedded document on the parent doc in Mongoid

Tags: mongoid, activemodel

I had to track the dirty objects. And it works fine with the parent
doc. But when I change the embedded or referenced in doc, the dirty
has to be accessed via the embedded/referenced in doc itself.

How can I track the dirty on the parent doc itself??

Answer (score 2):

I have put together mongoid extension to solve this problem https://github.com/versative/mongoid_relations_dirty_tracking. It simply tracks changes on document relations in the similar way as mongoid do it for attributes so the timestamps and versions are updated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Mongoid's own dirty attributes feature tracks changes to embedded documents. But it's not hard to implement basic dirty tracking of embedded documents yourself with something like this:

```
class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :foos
  attr_accessor :foos_changed
  alias_method :foos_changed?, :foos_changed
  # ...
end

class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :bar, :inverse_of => :foos
  after_save :notify_parent
  def notify_parent
    bar.foos_changed = true
  end
  # ...
end

b = Bar.create
b.foos_changed? # => nil
b.foos.create
b.foos_changed? # => true
```

If you need more options, like including embedded documents changes in `Bar.changes` or tracking the specific changes, you'll have to override the `changes` and `changed?` methods, which I wouldn't do unless you absolutely need those features.

Here's a way to track what changed in the embedded documents:

```
class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :foos
  attr_writer :embedded_changes
  def embedded_changes
    @embedded_changes ||= begin
      self._children.inject({}) do |memo, child|
        memo.merge( 
         {child.collection_name => {child.id => child.changes}} 
        ) if child.changed?
      end
    end
  end

  def changes
    original_value = super
    if original_value.blank?
      embedded_changes
    else
      original_value.merge(embedded_changes)
    end
  end

  def changed?
    super || self._children.any?(&:changed?)
  end
  # ...
end

class Foo
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :bar, :inverse_of => :foos
  # ...

  field :hat
end

b = Bar.create
f = b.foos.create
b.changes   # => nil 
b.changed?  # => false 
f.hat = 1
f.changes   # => {"hat"=>[nil, "1"]} 
b.changes   # => {"foos"=>{BSON::ObjectId('4cf...')=>{"hat"=>[nil, "1"]}}}    
b.changed?  # => true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its almost I wanted with some extra things.

Comment: What I'd want is whenever foo changes, I want to know via the bar.changed? and bar.changes to give those values. I think as you said, my need asks to override the changes and changed? methods. But how to do that?

Comment: See the updated answer above. Be careful though when you override `changes` and `changed?` . With complex documents, strange things could happen. There is a reason why Mongoid only tracks dirty attributes and no dirty associations.

Comment: Thanx. I'll get back after I try it out.

Comment: Great, it works. But I've got some other documents too with the references_many and references_one relationship. How can I track those referenced documents too just like the above one via the parent document? Will the above code just works or have to do some tweaks.

Comment: You will have to tweak and test the code if you want it to work with referenced objects. Instead of `_parent` and `_children`, you would have to use the `associations` method to find the referenced records.

Comment: I tried with the associations method, but couldn't figure out exactly. Since I'm not so meta-programmer in ruby, couldn't figure out. Here is the gist with the rspec setup. Just got to pass the last spec only. Can you look at it https://gist.github.com/721466

Comment: You have a basic problem. You can't just switch `_children` for `associations` and do nothing else. `_children` returns an array of documents but `associations` returns a hash with the association names as key and a `Mongoid::Associations::MetaData` object as the value. The first step is to update the `referenced_changes` method. I forked and updated your gist: https://gist.github.com/721971 . 
You will likely have to make other adjustments as well. I noticed your `changes` method and `changed?` method are not right either.

Comment: See comments in my fork of your gist on how to fix `changes` and `changed?` methods: https://gist.github.com/721971

Comment: I couldn't still fix it. Can you plz check the comment https://gist.github.com/721971#comments

Comment: I looked further into tracking changes to referenced docs and I don't think my approach will work. Embedded docs are fine though. The problem is that references work very differently than embedded docs and there are a lot of difficulties in tracking their changes. Sorry, but I can only recommend that you go with the embedded_changes only or find another way of solving the problem. FYI, there is a dirty_associations plugin for ActiveRecord: https://github.com/daphonz/dirty_associations